# What is the correct way of transmitting a PDF file data in xml node

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I am building an old fashion disconnected data exchange interface and part of it is to generate an xml with embedded Documents and PDF file data. The data will be travelling to the destination folder using SFTP and a gateway before reaching the specified network (packets will be encrypted, scanned by firewalls).

I am trying to embed a pdf document in an xml node with Base64 encoding as the xml envelope is subject to encryption.

```
<DataUpload>
<PdfData>*****</PdfData>
        ...
</DataUpload>
```

What is the correct way to defining the PDFData attribute? (see the code below showing two options)

xmlSerializer.Serialize(file,root) method will be used to dump xml file
In the first approach i can get the bytearry containing PDF data and in the second the pdf data (byte arry or stream) will be converted base64 string . Which approach is correct the first or second ?

```
 [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    public partial class DataUpload
    {
        // 1st Approach
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("PdfData", DataType = "base64Binary")]
        public byte[] PdfData { get; set; }

        // 2nd Approach
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("PdfData")]
        public string Base64StringPdfData { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Do they both work? What is the problem?

Comment: I think both approaches might work but i am not sure whether there is any specific problem when encryption is performed by subsequent systems which i do not have control. Hence want to be sure of correct  usage

Comment: Why not try it and find out!

Comment: If i had control/access on the network and how the data sent via sftp is used by the client's infrastructure then i should not have asked this question.

Comment: I mean try both approaches. I don't get why you can't just _try_ them.